# Add scala test to scala eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, scala, scalatest, scala-ide

I started with scala with eclipse and I have problems with adding ScalaTest to my project. I have already downloaded ScalaTest, but what next? I just starting with jvm and feel lost...

Comment: Did you add the jar to the project? Can you type a package.Classname and get autocompletition?

Answer (score 5):

Right click on the project, select Java Build Path, select the tab Libraries and Click on the button 'Add External Jars'. Select the jar that you've just downloaded and click OK. This should add scalatest to your Eclipse classpath.